# How to load API keys from .env file successfully

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, environment-variables, dotenv

I have been referring to tutorials on the web, but something keeps on going wrong even though I follow them exactly.

I am trying to hide some API keys inside .env file, this is the content of my .env(same directory as init.py):

```
CONNSTRING = DefaultEndpointsProtocol=samplesamplesameplsamplesample
```

and this is inside my init.py

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
load_dotenv(find_dotenv())
print(os.getenv("CONNSTRING"))
```

which does not work? not sure about the error, this is what it says:

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure  
Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__'

if usecwd or _is_interactive() or getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
  File "D:\\\", line 265, in _is_interactive
    main = __import__('__main__', None, None, fromlist=['__file__'])
```

Comment: Your snippets work on my Ubuntu environment. Only error I encounter is a missing `import os` statement in your _init.py_ .

Comment: The .env file should be inside the same folder as the _init.py_ ?   @MartinTovmassian          That is honestly so strange, when I pass the API key directly the app works, when I do the above it doesn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the *.env* should be at the same level as the file you execute.
But you can specify a path as parameter of the `load_dotenv` method.
Maybe you should try to get rid of the `find_dotenv` method and directly give the absolute path of your *.env* like so:

```
import os                                                                                                                                                                                                          
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
from pathlib import Path
load_dotenv(Path("/my/path/.env"))
print(os.getenv("CONNSTRING"))
```